# Find the x, y coordinates on outer edge of a circle based on degrees on html5 canvas

Tags: php, html, canvas

I have a circle on my canvas and I am trying to draw a line from the center to the outer edge based any given degree. The center of my circle is positioned at (110, 115) with a 100 radius.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.arc(110, 150, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI); //Circle
```

I am using PHP to get input and do the calculations using this

```
$x = 110 + 100 * cos($degrees);
$y = 150 + 100 * sin($degrees);
```

This will always put the end of the line at the outer edge of the circle, but it doesn't put it in the right place on the circle.

I entered 90 for $degrees and the line should be going straight right, but goes down and to the left instead.

[image: circle]

I have searched high and low, but have not found anyone trying to do this in canvas. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I changed my calculations to

```
$x = 110 + 100 * cos($degrees*pi()/180);
$y = 150 + 100 * sin($degrees*pi()/180);
```

and it treats the right center edge as 0 degrees, but I would like 0 to be on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

90° in canvas is straight down, while 0° is right, so you have to compensate for that.

To have 0° point up, simply swap *cos* and *sin* and subtract for y:

```
$x = 110 + 100 * sin($degrees * 3.14159 / 180);
$y = 150 - 100 * cos($degrees * 3.14159 / 180);
```

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var cx = 75, cy = 75, angle = 90;

var x = cx + 75 * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
var y = cy - 75 * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);

ctx.arc(cx, cy, 74, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been beating my head over this for hours.